# split my dataframe depending on the number of nodes pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, nodes, cluster-computing

I'm trying to split my dataframe depending on the number of nodes (of my cluster),

my dataframe looks like :

[image: originalDF]

If i had node=2, and dataframe.count=7 :

[image: desiredDF]

So, to apply an iterative approach the result of split will be :

[image: Node 1 -> 2 lines , Node 2 -> 2 lines , Node 1 -> 1 line (1 is the results of modulo )]

My question is : how can i do this ?

Comment: What is your expected result? Two objects (i.e. two dataframes) or one object with evenly distributed data on the cluster?

Comment: My expected result is to split my bloc of dataframes depending on the number of nodes (i.e if I had 10 lines in my dataframe and 3 nodes, the 1st node will takes 3 lines , the 2nd takes 3 lines , the 3d takes 3 lines and the last line will be in a node ( iterative approach)

Comment: But how many objects do you want? Four or three objects or just one?

Comment: if you mean an object is a dataframe, i want one dataframe (with variable size)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that (have a look at the code below) with one of the rdd partition functions, but I don't recommend it as
long as you are not fully aware of what you are doing and the reason why you are doing this. In general (or better for most usecase) it is better to let spark handle the data distribution.

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import itertools
import math

#creating a random dataframe
l = [(x,x+2) for x in range(1009)]

columns = ['one', 'two']

df=spark.createDataFrame(l, columns)

#create on partition to asign a partition key
df = df.coalesce(1)

#number of nodes (==partitions)
pCount = 5

#creating a list of partition keys
#basically it repeats range(5) several times until we have enough keys for each row
partitionKey = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.repeat(x, math.ceil(df.count()/pCount)) for x in range(pCount)))

#now we can distribute the data to the partitions
df = df.rdd.partitionBy(pCount, partitionFunc = lambda x: partitionKey.pop()).toDF()

#This shows us the number of records within each partition
df.withColumn("partition_id", F.spark_partition_id()).groupBy("partition_id").count().show()
```

Output:

```py
+------------+-----+ 
|partition_id|count| 
+------------+-----+ 
|           1|  202| 
|           3|  202| 
|           4|  202| 
|           2|  202| 
|           0|  201| 
+------------+-----+
```

Comment: thank u but it makes a problem in the part of convert to DF.[Stage 10:>                                                         (0 + 1) / 1]19/07/26 16:38:08 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 10.0 (TID 10)
 File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyspark\rdd.py", line 1771, in add_shuffle_key
    for k, v in iterator:
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: Is your partitionKey list long enough (i.e. equal or greater as df.count())? Can you please add the whole error message to your initial question?

Comment: Yes, my partitionKey is greater than df.count(), I added the whole error message

Comment: Where have added the whole error message? By the way, does my example work for you?

Comment: Yes, your example worked for me, (the whole error message is below)

Comment: the problem is in my dataframe, now it works for me, but it didn't works if i had a column with string type (it accepts only int types)